# Detecting HTML5 video play/pause state with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video, detect

I'm building a jQuery slideshow which will feature an HTML5 video player on one of the slides. Is there any way to get the jQuery slideshow to pause from its otherwise automatically running state, when it detects that the video is playing, besides a "slideshow play/pause" button?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can check if the video is paused used the `paused` property:

```
$("#videoID").get(0).paused;
```

You can pause a video using the `pause()` method:

```
$("#videoID").get(0).pause();
```

You can then resume the playback of the video using the `play()` method:

```
$("#videoID").get(0).play();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var video = $('video');

var videoElement = video.get(0);

if (!videoElement.paused) {}
```

One way of doing it using Jquery